# Inspect operator |> in OCaml's toplevel?

Tags: ocaml

I'd like to see the type of the operator `|>`, which is of course defined as `let |> x f = f x;;`.

With other operators, like `+`, I can simple hit `(+);;` and the toplevel will tell me it's `- : int -> int -> int = <fun>`.

But with `|>`, it says:

> Error: Failure: "|> must be applied to two arguments"

My question is, how can I inspect operator `|>` in OCaml's toplevel.

[image: Screen Shot]

Append:

OK. Now I know it has something to do with Core. If I define it directly it's OK. But in Core environment it just breaks.

This is my `.ocamlinit`:

```
(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;

#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
open Core.Std;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. Here's a complete command line session:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

#  let (|>) x f = f x;;
val ( |> ) : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
# (|>);;
- : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
#
```

**Update**

(Pascal Cuoq clearly has the right answer in the comments below. :-)

Comment: What?... Did you have anything special with environment?

Comment: @KevinLee The definition `let (|>) x f = f x` shown by Jeffrey can be quite inefficient. It is likely that in the Core/utop environment, `e1 |> e2` is defined with a syntax rule to be transformed immediately as `e2 e1`. This would explain why `(>|) ;;` is a syntax error.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks! That's reminds me of something. No wonder it should require `camlp4o`.

Comment: actually: ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# (|>);;  
- : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>

Comment: @user3240588 Yes, interesting, but what are you saying that isn't already included in the answer you are commenting on?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Well, only that |> is already defined in Pervasives (I guess). No need to define by hand. Apparently it's also optimized to eliminate any overhead over writing a standard function application.

Comment: @user3240588 Indeed, if you do `module P = Pervasives` you can see `external ( |> ) : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = "%revapply"`, i.e. `|>` is directly bound to a built-in operation.